# .bash_profile alias with variables

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to create an alias that will create a file and open it in VS Code.

Create an alias called `create <filename>` that will execute `touch <filename> && code <filename>`.

For example `create app.js` should execute `touch app.js && code app.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man bash`, under `ALIASES`:

> There  is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text.  If arguments are needed, a shell function should be  used  (see  FUNCTIONS below)."

Thus:

```
create() { touch "$1"; code "$1"; }
```

Comment: You should almost always double-quote variables (and parameters). Also, the function keyword is nonstandard; I'd recommend the syntax `create() { touch "$1"; code "$1"; }`

Comment: @GordonDavisson: I agree about quoting. I disagree about `function`: the tag is [tag:bash], not [tag:sh], and so the standard is whatever `man bash` says.

Comment: `man bash` says the `function` keyword is optional. Putting it there anyway simply makes your code less portable.

Comment: @tripleee: I guess I should also replace all `x++` in C with `x += 1` because Ruby can't understand `++`, just in case... Fine...

Comment: That's *reductio ad absurdum.* Shell scripts can be portable or specific to a particular shell. If you *need* features from a particular shell then of course striving for portability doesn't make any sense; but gratuitously wrecking otherwise portable code is just lazy.

Comment: @tripleee: If it was a script designed for distribution, I'd agree with you. But we're talking about a user wanting to customise his specifically bash environment. OP will stuff this into their `.bashrc` and never look at it again. The chance of OP ever running it on Bourne shell is less than the chance of me converting C code into Ruby. I haven't even _seen_ Bourne shell in the last twenty years. Why are you so hung up on portability?

Comment: Because it's not just the OP who ends up reading this. The broader argumentation is in my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat